# Pattern is not getting matched, showing 'Sanjay' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, perl

```
perl -n -e'if(/Avinash/../Sanjay/){next if(/Avinash|Sanjay/);    print "$_";}' avinash.txt>sumeet.txt
```

I want to write content between the Words Avinash and Sanjay in a file sumeet.txt, but when i am giving the pattern in next if ,it is throwing this error:

```
Sanjay' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message sounds like you're in `cmd` on Windows. `cmd` doesn't recognize `'` `'` as quoting symbols; you have to use double quotes (`"`) instead:

```
perl -n -e "if(/Avinash/../Sanjay/){next if(/Avinash|Sanjay/); print $_;}" avinash.txt>sumeet.txt
```

If your code uses `"` `"` strings internally, they can normally replaced by `qq(` `)`. But in your case I could just remove them entirely because `print $_` is perfectly valid code.

Comment: @AvinashTiwari Nice. (Consider [marking the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?)